# Get Object without specific property

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, ecmascript-5

Is there a way to deduct a specific property in order to make it cloneable (since the property may contain circles)?

Maybe something similar to this:

```
item = { a: 'A', b: 'B', circularProperty: somethingCircular };

$.extend(true,{},item.withoutProperties(['circularProperty']);
```

Answer (score 1):

using `delete` and temporary variable

```js
const item = {
  a: 'A',
  b: 'B',
  circularProperty: {
    a: 'A',
    b: 'B',
    circularProperty: {
      a: 'A',
      b: 'B'
    }
  }
};

let temp = item.circularProperty;

delete item.circularProperty;

console.log(item);

item.circularProperty = temp;

console.log(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
const { circularProperty, ...rest } = item;    
$.extend(true, {}, rest);
```

Comment: sorry, no ES6 available unfortunately

Comment: Unfortunately, the jquery.extend will not work this way: "deep-extending a cyclical data structure will result in an error."

Answer (score 0):

I know lodash has a `pick` method if I'm not mistaken, but I don't believe `jQuery` has built in operations for this.  You'd probably have to reconstruct the object.

```
var objectKeys = Object.keys(item);
var keysWithoutCircularProperty = objectKeys.filter(function(key){
    return key != 'circularProperty';
});

var shallowClone = keysWithoutCircularProperty.reduce(function(result, key) {
    result[key] = item[key];
    return result;
}, {});
```

Removed the arrow functions since you said no ES6 on the other answer.

Comment: Readability can always be improved to suite your own tastes.

Comment: what about deep cloning ?

Comment: Deep cloning would be related to the `$.extend()` call possibly.  This is just removing the key. Though, personally, I'd just stringify it and then parse it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```js
item = { a: 'A', b: 'B', circularProperty: 'abc' };
    function removeProperty(obj, propertyName) {
      let { [propertyName]: _, ...result } = obj
      return result
    }
    console.log(removeProperty(item, 'circularProperty'));
```